# Android equivalent of ImageRecorderIOS.openCameraDialog

Tags: android, ios, video, react-native, camera

On iOS to launch native camera UI to take photo/video recording we use `ImageRecorderIOS.openCameraDialog` - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagepickerios.html#opencameradialog - which has a success and error callback. This launches native camera UI and gets back photo/camera/cancel in the callback.

I dug around the docs to see if react-native had anything out of the box for this in Android I couldn't find it, did I miss something?

So then I looked for 3rd party libs, I found [`react-native-camera`](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera) however this creates a view I have to inlay within a `<View>` and i have to create my own controls. I then found `react-native-image-picker` which is perfect for photos, but it doesnt support video - https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker#directly-launching-the-camera-or-image-library - this launches the native camera, but it is only allowing me "photo" not "video". :( Does anyone have any 3rd party module for native android video taing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Intent to launch the default camera app and receive a photo or video from it. Details can be found in these guides:
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html

Try coding a solution based on them and come back if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks very much O.O. is there any way to launch a mixed of photo and video? So they can use the bottom toggle switch to toggle between video/photo? It seems with those two intents i can only launch video OR photo.